# Can't run ng lint on my angular-cli project

Tags: angular, angular-cli, lint

`ng -v`: 1.0.0-beta.32.3

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.4",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^3.2.0",
    "karma": "^1.4.1",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.6.0",
    "protractor": "^4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "^4.4.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3"
  }
```

**/tslint.json**

```
{
  "rulesDirectory": [
    "node_modules/codelyzer"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "class-name": true,
    "comment-format": [
      true,
      "check-space"
    ],
    "curly": true,
    "eofline": true,
    "forin": true,
    "indent": [
      true,
      "spaces"
    ],
    "label-position": true,
    "max-line-length": [
      false,
      140
    ],
    "member-access": false,
    "member-ordering": [
      true,
      "static-before-instance"
    ],
    "no-arg": true,
    "no-bitwise": true,
    "no-console": [
      true,
      "debug",
      "info",
      "time",
      "timeEnd",
      "trace"
    ],
    "no-construct": true,
    "no-debugger": true,
    "no-duplicate-variable": true,
    "no-empty": false,
    "no-eval": true,
    "no-inferrable-types": true,
    "no-shadowed-variable": true,
    "no-string-literal": false,
    "no-switch-case-fall-through": true,
    "no-trailing-whitespace": true,
    "no-unused-expression": true,
    "no-use-before-declare": true,
    "no-var-keyword": true,
    "object-literal-sort-keys": false,
    "one-line": [
      true,
      "check-open-brace",
      "check-catch",
      "check-else",
      "check-whitespace"
    ],
    "quotemark": [
      true,
      "single"
    ],
    "radix": true,
    "semicolon": [
      "always"
    ],
    "triple-equals": [
      true,
      "allow-null-check"
    ],
    "typedef-whitespace": [
      true,
      {
        "call-signature": "nospace",
        "index-signature": "nospace",
        "parameter": "nospace",
        "property-declaration": "nospace",
        "variable-declaration": "nospace"
      }
    ],
    "variable-name": false,
    "whitespace": [
      true,
      "check-branch",
      "check-decl",
      "check-operator",
      "check-separator",
      "check-type"
    ],

    "use-input-property-decorator": true,
    "use-output-property-decorator": true,
    "use-host-property-decorator": true,
    "no-input-rename": true,
    "no-output-rename": true,
    "use-life-cycle-interface": true,
    "use-pipe-transform-interface": true,
    "component-class-suffix": true,
    "directive-class-suffix": true
  }
}
```

**/src/tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "",
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom", "es2017.object"],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "angular2/*": [
        "@angular/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**.angular-cli.json**

```
{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.32.3",
    "name": "myapp"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "mobile": false,
      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/normalize-css/normalize.css",
        "styles.styl"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "addons": [],
  "packages": [],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "styl",
    "prefixInterfaces": false,
    "inline": {
      "style": false,
      "template": false
    },
    "spec": {
      "class": false,
      "component": true,
      "directive": true,
      "module": false,
      "pipe": true,
      "service": true
    }
  }
}
```

When I run `ng lint`, I get the yellow chalk error `No lint config(s) found. If this is not intended, run "ng update".` (which sounds really strange as the ng update command has been removed as of beta.32.3)

What could have gone wrong with the configuration?

Comment: Can you add your `.angular-cli.json` file? Did you do an upgrade to another cli version lately? Why don't you have @angular/cli in your `package.json`'s devDependencies?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4360

Comment: @Dinistro It was in main deps, I moved it now to devDeps. Yes, there's been a `yarn upgrade` on the project, probably has caused some mess.

Comment: @ParthGhiya Good point. I am glad Brocco and company will soon provide documentation on the angular-cli.json file!

Comment: @nuton.. yess!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You forgot to apply some breaking changes mentioned here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

To fix the linting problem, add following into the `.angular-cli.json` file.

```
"lint": [
   {
     "files": "src/**/*.ts",
     "project": "src/tsconfig.json"
   },
   {
     "files": "e2e/**/*.ts",
     "project": "e2e/tsconfig.json"
   }
],
```

It can also be, that your global and local versions of the cli are different. Please run following commands to make sure, that both have the same versions (I would directly upgrade to rc.0):

```
npm i -g @angular/cli@1.0.0-rc.0

rm -rf node_modules/ 

npm i -D @angular/cli@1.0.0-rc.0
npm i
```

After this, you should have the newest version globally and locally

Comment: I had this case before, but then I was getting a message that my local version is used, which was a very good strategy. So, unless they changed that strategy, I don't believe this would be a problem. Thanks for bringing it up though.